# Proper way to serve updated files without user refreshing on nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, static-files

This is a pretty core question. I have a django app that I run in an nginx/gunicorn configuration. Nginx is responsible for proxying to gunicorn, but it also serves the static files of the project directly.

The issue is, when I update the static files, the browser doesn't load the latest version. Sometimes a refresh fixes it, but sometimes it requires clearing the cache. (I should mention I'm using require.js, which does not help).

To alleviate this issue I'm doing this trick:

```
VERSION = '2.03'
STATIC_URL = '/static/' + VERSION + '/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static/' + VERSION + '/'
```

This way, when I change static files, I simply bump the version. But for various reasons, I need to stop doing this. Is there a way to configure nginx to better serve updated static files when they are available?

I'm just not sure if the browser or nginx is to blame.

**Update:** Here's my nginx configuration with the comments removed:

```
upstream mycoolsite_server {
  server unix:/webapps/mycoolsite/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.mycoolsite.com;
    return       301 http://mycoolsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name mycoolsite.com 42.42.42.42;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /webapps/mycoolsite/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/mycoolsite/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /webapps/mycoolsite/site/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /webapps/mycoolsite/site/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://mycoolsite_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /webapps/mycoolsite/site/static/;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you're running ./manage.py collectstatic after each update? Can you please post your nginx config?

Comment: Yep, that'd be too easy. :P I posted the configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set expire for the static files in nginx configuration. For example if you don't want to cache css, js and png files. you can define sth. like:

```
location ~* \.(css|js|png)$ {
    expires 0;
    break;
}
```

so they won't been cached. But i assume you are making ./manage.py collectstatic after you change your static files on your repository or dev. environment.

Comment: The problem is I'd like to still allow the browser to cache for performance reasons, but doesn't the browser send some type of header to the server that lets the server determine if it needs to download a fresh version?

Comment: ok i got your point. here is your cure :) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage

Comment: Close! That's a nice solution, but unfortunately it would break compatibility with r.js.

Comment: Ultimately I ended up using nginx expire, but I used 2h for js and css. Thanks!

Comment: For future readers, the correct way to disable caching is "expires off" (which is the default) because "expires 0" tells nginx actually to add the header “Cache-Control: max-age=t.” which defaults to an expiration of 1 month. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires